# Protractor - more than one element found for locator by.css(.....)

Tags: javascript, css, protractor

In my application there are couple of rows and in each row last column, there is option of 'Edit'|'Delete' and when click on Edit, on the same place we get option for 'Update'|'Cancel', I successfully clicked on edit, made some changes and when I try to click on update it throws an error:

> more than one element found with locator `by.css(..)` as both have same code

```
<td>
<div class="biometricActionCln ng-hide" ng-show="!list.isEditable" style="">
<a ng-click="editBiometrics(list, $index)">
**<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o">**
</i> Edit</a>
<span> | </span>
<div ng-show="list.isEditable" class="" style="">
<a ng-click="manageEditBiometric(editBiometric, 'Modify', list.biometricId)">
**<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o">**
</i> Update</a>
<span> | </span>
</div>
</td>
```

Kindly let me know how do I click on update link.

Answer (score 5):

```
Below are different ways of handling multiple elements.

accessing multiple elements with index:
element.all(by.css('.selector'))[0]
element.all(by.css('.selector'))[1]

accessing multiple elements by calling methods:
element.all(locator).first();
element.all(locator).last();

accessing multiple elements through callback function:
element.all(by.css('.selector')).then(function(elements) {
  // elements is an array of ElementFinders.
});
```

Comment: Thank u, but i need to identify the row by name(first column), click on edit do some changes in the field and click on update.
for clicking on edit i have used
`element.all(by.repeater("list in biometricsList")).filter(function(_tableRow){
                    return _tableRow.element(by.css("td:nth-child(1)")).getText().then(function(name){
                            return name == "name1"; 
                    }) 
                  }).first().element(by.css("i.fa-pencil-square-o")).click();`
i need click on update link of this particular row only

Comment: If you are doing inline edit, most probably 'update' button only visible in the current row where you are editing. why don't you try using linkText selectors. element(by.linkText('Update')) or element(by.partialLinkTex ('Update'))